# Need to retrieve data using express, my own url and AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am getting into retrieving data from my server by using express. I have a button that needs to display names after click, but it does not seem to be working. I keep getting an error that says 'require' is not defined and when I click the search button I get an error message:

***jquery.js:9631 GET http://localhost:10000/ send @ jquery.js:9631ajax @ jquery.js:9176displayTurtles @ serverFS.js:35dispatch @ jquery.js:4641elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4309
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:10000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.***

I need to show the turtles in a list on the HTML and later also allow user to add new turtle objects using the POST method.

server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
      var turtles = {
      message: "success",
      data: [
        {
          name: "Raphael",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Leonardo",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Donatello",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Michelangelo",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        }
      ]
    };
      res.send(turtles)
})

server.listen(10000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

serverFS.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var turtleList = $('<ol class="theList">')
    $('.DTurtles').append(turtleList);

    $(document).on('click', '#show', displayTurtles);
});

function displayTurtles(){  

    var emptyArray = [];

    var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:10000/" + turtleSearch;

    $.ajax({url: myQueryUrl, method: 'GET'}).done(function(response){

        var loopLength = response.data.length;
        var name;
        var food;
        for(var x = 0; x < loopLength; x++) {

            var emptyTurt = {};
            name = response.data[x].name;
            food =  response.data[x].favFood;

            emptyTurt.name = name;
            emptyTurt.food = food;

            emptyArray.push(emptyTurt);
        } 
        console.log(emptyArray)

    });
    console.log(emptyArray)

}
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <form>
            <label for="search-input">Type Something</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="search-input"><br><br>
            <input id="show" type="button" value="For Emergencies Only">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="DTurtles">
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="serverFS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Do i need to be specific with my get function on the server.js file? I read on the express website and it said for route parameters do:

```
Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I keep getting an error that says 'require' is not defined

`server.js` is clearly designed to be run via Node.js and not embedded in a web page.

> The response had HTTP status code 404.

The URL is throwing a 404 error.

Assuming you are running `server.js` through Node.js (in addition to trying, and failing, to run it in the browser directly) this is probably because you typed something other than `turtles` into the search box. `/turtles` is the only URL the server is set up to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your `server.js` file is a designed to run in node.js on your own server.  It does not run in a web page in a browser.

So, this cannot be done in web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="server.js"></script>
```

Instead, you have to run that file with node.js as in:

```
node server.js
```

And, if you do it on the right host, you can then access that server with an Ajax call from your web page.

Note: Browsers enforce a same origin limitation on making Ajax calls so you will either have to put your web page and the ajax call on the same origin (e.g. serve the web page from your express server and load it from there in the browser) or you will have to enable CORS in your express server so it will tell the browser that a cross origin request is OK.

---

If you're only trying to add a route for a single web page, you can do that like this:

```
app.get("/index.html", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/somePath/index.html");
});
```

Then, you would load the web page as `http://localhost:10000/index.html`.

If you're trying to add a route for many web pages, then you would put them all in one common directory and use [`express.static()` middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express).

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "someDirectoryName"));
```

Comment: I did run the node server.js and the .listen function worked by showing me the test alert. But the data is not being retrieved and shown on my html

Comment: @H.Lee - Then why are you including it in your web page.  Remove that.  As I say in my answer, you also have a same origin issue, probably because you are loading the web page from the file system and then trying to access your server.   You need to load the web page from your web server and then you can access that same server via ajax from that web page.  You will need to add a route to your web server for the web page itself.

Comment: I got rid of the tag on the bottom. How do I load a web page from y web server and also add a route to my web server for the web page

Comment: @H.Lee - See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: what does sendFile do. I just want to retrieve the names in the turtle object in my server.js file and display it as a list in my html.

Comment: @H.Lee - Look, we'd love to help you, but first you should look in the Express documentation for `sendFile()` and ask a bit more specific a question after reading that.